# When using a multiple-output matlab function, do i need to callback all variables?

Tags: matlab

When using a multiple-output matlab function, do i need to callback all variables? or can I just take the first two variables? (if so..is it not recommended?)

lets say in function.m

`[a, b, c] = function( )`

in main.m

`[var1, var2] = function;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling (almost) any function in matlab you can request fewer outputs than it specifies. So, yes the example you give should work perfectly fine.

There are some clever things you can do with this, such as using [nargout](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) within a function to see how many output arguments have been requested and only calculating the values that have been requested as an optimisation trick.

Comment: But beware - some (IMNSHO slightly dubious) functions will change behaviour and return different things if you request fewer outputs than they can supply.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the definition of the function, and exactly which of the outputs you want to get.

Not all the function allow to do it, you can find all the options for each function in the beginning of the help documentation on the specific function.

If you want only the 2nd, or 3rd outputs, and you want also to save the computation-time of the results that does not interesting, you can use `~` option, like this (for versions 2009b and later):

```
[~, var1, var2]=function
```

Comment: Note: the tilde trick only appeared in Matlab 2009b, so if your scripts need to work on earlier versions you might want to avoid it. [Loren on the art of Matlab](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/)

Comment: +1. Note that the tilde to ignore outputs was introduced in R2009b, which breaks compatibility with older versions.

Comment: You right, I added it. I myself using 2008a, but forgot to write it :)

Comment: Using `~` does not save time by preventing the output being computed. It simply doesn't return the output.

Answer (score 0):

Many functions allow for options to passed that change how the function behaves. I used/wrote various numerical solving functions a bit and one that nice amount of option, for instance is the [LSMR function(s)](http://www.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsmr.html).

Otherwise, if you can manipulate the original either introduce an input(s) to do so before or at the end with an inline subroutine to generate the outputs you want.

Or if you can't it will return as either a cell array or a vector and you can pass an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/tips-and-tricks-combining-functions-using-anonymous-functions.html) to generate the desired outputs that way.

Really, can be done many ways. Very contextual.